# Can't test published Expo project on Expo GO when not developping it

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on a `react-native` app using `expo`.

I have no problem to display the application on my Android Phone using the QR CODE provided by `Metro Builder`.
But I would like my customers to be able to see my project even when i'm not working on it.

I published my application using `expo publish` and `Metro Builder` gave me a link that is similar to this : `https://expo.io/@USERNAME/projects/MyProjectName`. My project is in `unlisted` visibility, so that anyone with the link can see it.
Yet, i'm not able to open it in my Android Expo application. When I visit the link, it doesn't ask me to open it with Expo, and there's no button to do it. If I try to copy the link to my clipboard, and then click `Open from clipboard` in Expo Go, it will open the navigator again.

I also tried to generate a QR CODE from the link, but it does the same.

How do you open your project in Expo Go when you're not into development ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the QR code which already generated by expo is provided in that project link eg. `https://expo.io/@USERNAME/MyProjectName` or with [release channel](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/release-channels/) `https://expo.io/@USERNAME/MyProjectName?release-channel=MyReleaseChannelName`

Take a screenshot of that QR code and send it. Regardless of the project visibility they will be able to install the app by scanning it with their phone.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Tho i'm not sure I understand. That link doesn't provide any QR CODE, it only show the application name, icon and description ?

Comment: @Ezhno Now I've edited my comment and provided the correct path, can you please check again?